# How do I define a template file for a specific node paragraph ID?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I would like the ability to override a template for only 1 paragraph.  Is it possible to override just one paragraph like we can with nodes node-{nodeid}.html.twig?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by implementing [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x) from within a custom module or your theme. After that you can override paragraphs by adding templates like `paragraph--123.html.twig` to your theme's template directory.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE/MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_paragraph_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $paragraph_id = $variables['elements']['#paragraph']->id();
  $suggestions[] = 'paragraph__' . $paragraph_id;
}
```